# jQuery кавычки в списке атрибутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем добра. Не могу понять как экранировать вставку переменной в списке атрибутов.

```js
var srck=data[0]['src'];
var alter=data[0]['alter'];
                 
$('img .second-slide').attr({'src': srck,'alt':alter}); // вот здесь
```

```
  переменные srck и alter нужно вставить в кавычках, чет не врублюсь как.
```

Comment: На первый взгляд всё верно. Что у вас хранится в `srck` и `alter`?

Comment: `$('img .second-slide')` Тут точно ошибка, лишний пробел, вы у тега `<img />` ищите потомка с классом `.second-slide`

Comment: @ Евгений Миронов спасибо это был пробел.